# Cassandra sstable2json not working in 1.0

Tags: java, cassandra

I am beginning to experiment with Cassandra. I am trying out the sstable2json backup tool and it dies with an exception. I do:

```
sstable2json /home/username/Standard1-e-1-Data.db
```

and it gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTable.estimateRowsFromIndex(SSTable.java:250)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:328)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:158)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:122)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:117)
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.export(SSTableExport.java:353)
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.export(SSTableExport.java:366)
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.main(SSTableExport.java:424)
```

The file /home/username/Standard1-e-1-Data.db exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I had the wrong db file path. The correct invocation should have been:

```
sstable2json /var/lib/cassandra/data/MyKeyspace/User-h-1-Data.db
```